# Symfony2 Column cannot be null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

Hello i have problem with Sonata bundle when i want to create new post i get message

> > [2/3] DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO post (title, status, body, created, updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
> >     ?)' with params ["Hello World", 1, "asdasda", null, "2014-04-29
> >     18:05:10"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created'
>   cannot be null

In my entity class i use **@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()** for created and updated actions.

Entity

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Post
     *
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     * @ORM\Table(name="post")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ISLab\Bundles\BlogBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
     */
    class Post
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $title;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
         */
        private $status;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text", nullable=true)
         */
        private $body;

        /**
         * @var datetime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
         */
        private $created;

        /**
         * @var datetime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="datetime")
         */
        private $updated;
```

This is method what i use in entity for create and update.

```
/*
 * Set Date Created
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function setCreated()
{
    return $this->created = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}

/**
 * Get Date Created
 *
 * @return Post
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * Set Date Modified
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 *
 * @return Post
 */
public function setUpdated()
{
    $this->updated = new \DateTime();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Udated Date
 *
 * @return Post
 */
public function getUpdated()
{
    return $this->updated;
}
```

Update action work fine and he is allways automaticly called when i edit any post. But when i try to create new post created value is null idk whay?

Answer (score 4):

According to the error message, the `created` attribute is `null` when you insert the new entity. You **have to** set a value for this attribute.

You can set it in the Entity class constructor:

```
class Post
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }
    ...
```

Or you can set it before persisting your entity by calling `setCreated()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function prePersist()
{
    if ($this->created == null) $this->created = new \DateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Gedmo Doctrine2 extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md) provide a standard solution for this problem.

Here is an example with corresponding annotations:

```
<?php

namespace ISLab\Bundles\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ISLab\Bundles\BlogBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $enabledAt;
```